# Bash run function and execute key command without '&'

Tags: linux, bash

I have a function that executes and take a while to run. While it runs it spits out important information that I need to be able to see.

I would like to be able to trigger a key command with xdotool and open a new tab in my terminal so that I may run another function as well.

I have read about using '&' which works HOWEVER, that causes the previous function to run in the background and I don't see the output of the function while it runs.

There has to be a solution for me I am just not familiar enough with bash I assume to search for the correct terminology.

Comment: Run both the commands in background using & and you should be able to see the o/p of both on the terminal.. You would need to figure out yourself which o/p belongs to which script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nohup.

```
nohup your_command &
```

The output goes to `nohup.out`.

Comment: so when i try that I get `nohup: failed to run command ‘_custom_function’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

use output redirection to write a log file which you can later access or use `tail -f <log_file>` to track real-time progress:

`command > log.txt 2>&1 &`

The `2>&1` will redirect stderr to stdout. the `>` will then redirect stdout to a file. You will see both regular output as well as error messages in `log.txt`.